# Input type email: limit local part max length

Tags: regex, html, email

How I can restrict emails with local part (text before `@`) longer than 64 with `pattern` attribute?

```
 <input type="email" id="email" name="email"
        required="required" class="form-control">
```

Example: `1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234+x@example.com` shouldn't be accepted

Comment: Take a look here https://embed.plnkr.co/MLuuNdUEhauXYTI29hsQ/?show=preview (specially in email.directive.ts)

Comment: You could try `\w{1, 64}@.+`.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn just a little correction, if you don't specify the start of the string it would match longer strings `^[\w+]{1,64}@.+$` would work.

Comment: @RodrigoFerreira it works, however now i am not able to use non word characters like dot

Comment: Use `pattern="(?![^@]{65})[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_\`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*"`. The pattern is from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#Basic_validation

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks. works fine

Answer (score 1):

In [*Basic validation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#Basic_validation) section, MDN `input` docs say that

> Browsers that support the "email" input type automatically provide validation to ensure that only text that matches the standard format for Internet email addresses is entered into the input box. Browsers that implement the specification should be using an algorithm equivalent to the following regular expression:
>
> `` /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@a-zA-Z0-9?(?:.a-zA-Z0-9?)*$/ ``

You may use this pattern, or any other that meets your requirements, and add a `(?![^@]{65})` lookahead at the start that will fail any input with 65 or more non-`@`s at the start. In an HTML5 regex, you may even remove the `^` at the start and `$` at the end of the string as they are added automatically.

So, you may use

```
pattern="(?![^@]{65})[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*"
```